# Using Indices to get Index in a ForEach loop SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and I am trying to get the index for the following ForEach Loop

```
ForEach(self.postViewModel.posts, id: \.postId) { post in
                      
                                                       HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 25) {
                                                           Header(post : post)
                                                           Footer(post: post)
```

I have tried using indices as in the following:

```
 ForEach(self.postViewModel.posts.indices, id: \.postId) { post in
```

but I got this error

```
Value of type 'Range<Array<Post>.Index>.Element' (aka 'Int') has no member 'postId'
```

I have also tried using index but obviously it wouldn't work since index isn't in the loop

```
ForEach(self.postViewModel.posts, id: \.postId) { post in
                           
                                                           HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 25) {
                                                               Header(post : post)
                                                               Footer(post: post)
                                                           Text("#\(index)").frame(width: 45, height: 30)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the variant of `indices`, you should use `self` as `id`

```
ForEach(self.postViewModel.posts.indices, id: \.self) { post in
```

Possible variant to have both

```
ForEach(Array(self.postViewModel.posts.enumerated()), 
    id: \.1.postId) { (index, post) in
```